# Read highlighted text from a picture using tesseract

Tags: opencv, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to read text from an image using `tesseract`, the picture is high qualit, so `tesseract` is able to read the text with 95% accuracy, which is OK for me at this point, however `tesseract` in unable to read the text which is highlighted (selected), Please refer the PIC

[image]

How can i read the text from selected area using `tesseract`, Is there any way to identify which word is highlighted in the image ?

Code used to read and convert the text from image as below.

```c
tesseract::TessBaseAPI *myOCR = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();

//cout << "hello" << endl;

if (myOCR->Init("C:\\QTSoftware\\IODriver\\", "eng")) {

    SaveLineLog(brdInd, "Unable to initialize tesseract engine", __LINE__); 

    return RC_TESSERACT_ENG_FAILURE;

    //fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract.\n");

    //return RC_THREAD_FAILURE;
    //exit(1);
}

SaveLineLog(brdInd, "tesseract engine is UP :)", __LINE__);

//strcpy_s(fileName, "C:\\TEMP\\T481Logs\\FrameOCR23_0.jpg");

FILE *pFile;

fopen_s(&pFile,fileName, "r");    // Open picture

PIX* pix;                         // Image format from `leptonica`

pix = pixReadStreamBmp(pFile);

fclose(pFile);

//Pix *pix = pixRead(fileName);

//Pix *pix = pixReadStreamBmp(fileName);

//cout << "Tesseract - Pix : " << pix << endl;

if (pix == NULL)
{
   SaveLineLog(brdInd, "Pix failure", __LINE__); 

   return RC_TESSERACT_PIX_FAILURE;
}

myOCR->SetImage(pix);

char* outText = myOCR->GetUTF8Text();
```

Comment: Can you attach the code you are using, are you performing any kind of pre-processing before passing the image to tesseract method ?

Comment: i have used the above code in application to invoke 'tesseract' and get the text from the image, since all the images are black and white , so pre-processing was not required, now  i found that `tesseract` is ignoring the highlighted text so i may try to pre-process.

Answer (score 1):

If all images have this format, you can first invert colors, then use Threshold binarization to get rid of this shadow.
It's better always to pre-process and provide clean image to the OCR engine, it will probably enhance the detection percent too.

Comment: i understand that , i may need to pre-process before passing the image to `tesseract`, how do i identify the highlighted text in the image ? - thanks

Comment: @PankajMishra what i suggested fixes the issue of not being able to 'read' the highlighted part, but to identify it, this would need some more info